# C++ operator overloading <double> - <Matrix>

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, overloading, operator-keyword

Let's suppose that we want to subtract some  value from a given matrix.
How could/should I overload that operator.

***main.cpp***

```
Matrix<double> m(10, 5);

auto r = 1.0 - m; //error: return type specified for 'operator double'
```

***matrix.hpp***

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
  Matrix operator double(T val) {
    Matrix tmp(rows, cols);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        const unsigned int idx = VecToIdx({i, j});
        tmp[idx] = val - this[idx];
      }

    return tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: `operator double` is a conversion operator that should return a `double` not a `Matrix`

Comment: operator `double` converts Matrix to double, not double to Matrix. Did you mean to have a matrix constructor that takes a double?

Comment: You can't! However, you can overload the `operator-(double, Matrix)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to subtract a `Matrix` from a `double`, but your question asks to subtract a `double` from a `Matrix` instead. Those are two different operations. What do you really want to do?

In the latter case, you need to overload the subtraction operator, not the conversion operator, eg:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix operator- (T val) {
        Matrix tmp(rows, cols);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                const unsigned int idx = VecToIdx({i, j});
                tmp[idx] = (*this)[idx] - val;
            }
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

```
Matrix<double> m(10, 5);

auto r = m - 1.0;
```